# After deployment to server codeigniter app gives 404

Tags: codeigniter

I'm developing on Mac OSX with MAMP. My app is built on top of CodeIgniter 1.7.2 and works fine on my develoment machine.

Now I copied the to my test environment, which is Ubuntu Server 9.10.

A standard, fresh CI install works perfectly but when I put my app in the same dir, I get errors.

If I just go to my root, I get a 404. On my dev machine, it is also under the root, not in a folder.

If I use the full path, it works but I get errors that a library could not be loaded and stuff.

What is going on here :s

Comment: 2013 - this is still relevant and the answer below still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it, it seems the controllers are case sensitive (why?)

If my url is http://example.com/setcal/thefunction but the controller filename is named SetCal.php (and the class SetCal) then it is not found.

I rename the file and class to all lowercase and it works fine.

I find that strange though. Isn't mac (dev machine) supposed to be case sensitive too?

And why on earth is there case sensitivity in the first place? What is the point?

Comment: +2 In the Class and Method Naming section of the General Style and Syntax section of the CodeIgniter User Guide states that we should never use CamelCased for class and function names.

Comment: I can report that this problem is still occurring MAMP Dev to CentOS Production server. January 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might happening due to some directory permission errors. do a `#ls -l` and compare the permissions on both your fresh CI dir and your existing project dir.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

solution: config.php change row

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```